# Is there a userscript to put links to Teams back in the left nav?

Tags: support, script-request

Teams are moving to [their own domain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420980/what-does-teams-getting-its-own-domain-mean-practically) and as such, my freemium team where I keep some useful-for-work knowledge has now disappeared from the left nav, which annoys me.

I'm looking for a userscript that can help me put a link to my team back into the left nav, does anyone know if one exists already?

Comment: Are you looking for *just* a link, or are you needing it to be "live" (i.e. show current activity indicator). Adding just a link for a list of Teams that are hard coded in the userscript is fairly easy, but is more complex if the links for the specific Teams are not hard coded in the userscript (i.e. if the script either determines what Teams you are in and/or allows you to specify or indicate that you want a specific Team there). Having it display activity is notably more complex.

Comment: Hint for implementation: A GET to `https://stackoverflowteams.com` will redirect to the user's most recently viewed Team. Their list of Teams on stackoverflowteams.com will be in the `#team-switcher-popover` dropdown in the topbar. That page could be fetched every so often, the list extracted, somewhat manipulated (e.g. remove the bg-orange-500 and fc-white classes), and cached (i.e. don't fetch it on *every* SE site page load). It could then be inserted into the left-nav.

Comment: @Makyen just the link is fine for me. It's my own team without anyone else in it, so no useful notifications coming from it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Custom Sidebar Links

<kbd>[Install](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/custom-sidebar-links/raw/main/sidebar.user.js)</kbd>

I've written a Tampermonkey userscript called Custom Sidebar Links that allows for custom links in the SE sidebar.

I've given it [a dedicated question](https://stackapps.com/q/9582/92477).