# Custom Sidebar Links

Tags: script, tampermonkey, left-sidebar

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Custom Sidebar Links is designed for adding user-selected links to the sidebar. By default, it includes a link to the Stack Overflow Teams website, as well as a link to Google. The links can be customized as desired. For example, one could add a link to a chat room to the sidebar.

This was created because (1) SO Teams are being removed from the sidebar and (b) because having general links (say, to a chat room) could be useful. It was created be me.

The userscript locates the sidebar, adds some misc. HTML elements, and then adds the user-defined links one-by-one, in a loop.

#### License

MIT License - see also [the LICENSE file](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/custom-sidebar-links/blob/main/LICENSE) in the GitHub repo

#### Download

<kbd>[Install](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/custom-sidebar-links/raw/main/sidebar.user.js)</kbd>

#### Platform

Tampermonkey userscript - I personally use it on a Chromium-based browser on Windows, but it should also work in other browsers on other platforms with Tampermonkey installed.

### Contact

I've created this. Feel free to [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/custom-sidebar-links/issues) or let me know here. I'm [frequently in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/525173/cocomac), too.

### Code

I've written this in JavaScript, as it is a userscript. The code is in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/custom-sidebar-links).

#### TODOs

If you'd like me to add something and don't see it here, let me know (either by [posting an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/better-sidebar/issues) or by leaving a comment)

| Task | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Rename the variable called `dafrfaavarjkgf` to something descriptive | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| Add a UI for adding and removing links | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |
| Automatically detect Teams the user is in and add them | [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) |

### Adding/removing links

To add/remove links, there is a section in the userscript that looks like this - just change the URLs/titles as desired, and of course, you can add more lines. For example, to add a link titled `Tavern on the Meta` with a link to that chatroom, you would add `URLs.set("Tavern on the Meta", "https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta");` to that section.

```js
/// CUSTOM LINKS GO HERE ///
URLs.set("SO Teams Site", "https://stackoverflowteams.com");
URLs.set("Google", "https://google.com");
```